# How to insert an image in video that changes its bounds to fit in chosen area?

Tags: video-editor

I have a video template of an advert for a mobile app and all I want is to insert an image to that video that will fit in bounds of the phone in advertisement, in that video the phone rotates and changes its position so it is important for image to adjust.

Comment: This is not a video production question as defined by the guidelines of the board.  A mere video screen does not make something a video production.  Story, characters, lighting, sound, sound design, music, editing, costumes, makeup, sets, special effects, cameras, lenses, etc.  Those make for video production.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is about programming and display, not video production.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you are looking for a way to **Match Move**ment of the photo (picturing screen contents) to the movement of the actual mobile phone in the video.

This is usually done through **Motion Tracking** tools within your video editing software.

The specific ways of achieving this would different depending on the software you use. For example, [this part of the official documentation](https://support.apple.com/kb/PH16562?locale=en_US&viewlocale=en_US) explains how you could achieve that in Motion

[This video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zDnkdw2Bnz4) covers your specific example with a mobile phone screen in After Effects